# Datatables table tool ->only displaying records are exported csv file?

Tags: jquery

I am using datatables ,table tool to export csv file.It works fine but its exporting only displayed records in the table.But I want to export all the records how to do that?

Comment: code code and more code!

Comment: You should accept some responses. It'll make people more inclined to respond

Comment: oh k PhD..................................

Comment: a very appropriate post I just read on this subject: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                /* Initialise the DataTable */
                var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
                    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                    "oTableTools": {
                        "aButtons": [ {
                                "sExtends": "ajax",
                                "sButtonText": "CSV Export",
                                "fnClick": function( nButton, oConfig ) {
                                    var oParams = this.s.dt.oApi._fnAjaxParameters( this.s.dt );
                                    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                                    iframe.style.height = "0px";
                                    iframe.style.width = "0px";
                                    iframe.src = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/alarm/generate_csv"+"?"+$.param(oParams);
                                    document.body.appendChild( iframe );
                                }
                            } ]
                    )};
```

I tried this it works fine...anyway thanks guys

Comment: I try this but it doesn't open any window to save the records.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/index.html) example which export all records.

Comment: no yaar...I am using server side datatables,so it just showing particular displayed record only...